# Weird regex in inherit.js (by John Resig) - why, what and how?

Tags: javascript, regex, prototype, resig

I recently used a [little utility library](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) by John Resig, called [inherit.js](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/). I usually try to understand the core parts of the libraries I am using, and after a lot of head scratching I finally understood the hard bits of the code (namely how he could call the corresponding method of the super class).

The 1% bit I do not get is related to a regex

```
fnTest = /xyz/.test(function(){xyz;}) ? /\b_super\b/ : /.*/;
```

1. The regex /xyz/ is tested against a *function*. Both [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/a55e5s6b%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) state that `test` takes a string as the argument. No mention of a function, but since there are no errors in the console, I guess it must fly, but how does it work?
2. The next WTF is that the function body is `xyz;`. This function cannot be executed, because it would otherwise result in a "`ReferenceError: xyz is not defined`". Right? So what does it do?
3. If the result of the test is true, then `fnTest` is equal to a regex which checks for `_super` on a word boundary, else a regex that matches on anything. Double WTF; again how and why.

Later on there is a related bit of code, where this regex is being used.

```
  // Check if we're overwriting an existing function
  prototype[name] = typeof prop[name] == "function" &&
    typeof _super[name] == "function" && fnTest.test(prop[name])
        ? aFunctionThatCanCallSuper /* Lots of code */
        : prop[name];
```

The bit I am wondering about here is `fnTest.test(prop[name])`. I understand all the other tests, which check if the property exists, is a function, etc, but not what the regex test does. Anyone?

Comment: [Understanding John Resig's 'Simple JavaScript Inheritance'](http://blog.buymeasoda.com/understanding-john-resigs-simple-javascript-i/)

Comment: @Andreas: Wow, wish I found that earlier, just had to decipher this thing, but seems my findings are correct.

Comment: Not even worth posting my answer, that link seems like the perfect answer. I'm guessing if you were to redo this library _today_ that check isn't necessary given that modern browsers will serialize correctly.

Comment: Great link! But for free points, you could post a quick sum up of the relevant points (or I will in a couple of days) :)

Comment: As I've only copied a link let @elclanrs write his answer one more time and reward him for his effort :)

Comment: @Andreas: When I deleted the answer I got rid of the edits, effectively loosing the answer but I'll sum it up so OP can close this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **what**:

`test` only takes strings as input, so a function will be `toString`ed, like will any other object that's not a string. `xyz` is not interpreted as a variable, but as a string, so it won't throw a reference error. This happens in other places as well, take this for example:

```
var a = function(){}; var b = function(){};
console.log(a + b); // `+` coerces with `toString`
```

The **why**:

The serialization of functions in old browsers is not reliable and might not output the `_super` property in the function's body, but (I'm assuming) something like `function{[native code]}` or `[object Object]`; in those cases use a regex such as `/.*/` to match anything and not perform the optimizations that can be done in browsers that output the correct result.

Related links for more info:

http://blog.buymeasoda.com/understanding-john-resigs-simple-javascript-i/ (found by Andreas)
http://es5.github.io/x15.3.html#x15.3.4.2
http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/747203-function-tostring